# sql server Reporting Services for subtotals

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new SSRS 
I have table that looks like

```
   Month Sales 
   Aug    222
   Aug    500
   Sep    80
   Sep    100
```

I want totals Sales in  total sales of AUG and  total sales SEP separately .
It should look like

Month                        Sales

Total sales in Aug

Total sales in Sep

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Row Group on `Month` field and use `=SUM(Fields!Sales.Value)` to get the total per month, only if you are using a tablix.

If you don't want to use a tablix but you want to show the values in separated textboxes you can use expressions like this for every month:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Month.Value = "Aug",Fields!Sales.Value,0),"DataSetName")
```

Replace `"Aug"` by the month you want to get the total.

Let me know if this helps.